# Using MasterDetailPage or ToolbarItem throws exception on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, exception, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I have the following two pieces of XAML code in a Xamarin.Forms Portable Library XAML project:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.TestView">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding ToolbarItemText}" Command="{Binding ToolbarItemCommand}" Order="Default" Priority="0"/>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.Test2View">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Currencies">
      
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <ContentPage>
        </ContentPage>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

When running the Windows Phone 8.1 project (WinRT, not Silverlight), I have the following exception:

> E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
>
> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you **HAVE TO** specify the **icon paths** for the **MasterDetailPage.Master** page and for the **ToolbarIcon**. Additionally for the **MasterDetailPage.Master** page, you have to specify the **Title** property.

Here are the corrected code samples:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.TestView">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding ToolbarItemText}" Command="{Binding ToolbarItemCommand}" Order="Default" Priority="0">
      <ToolbarItem.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
               Android="my-icon"
               WinPhone="Assets/my-icon.png" />
      </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.Test2View">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Currencies">
      <ContentPage.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
               Android="my-icon"
               WinPhone="Assets/my-icon.png" />
      </ContentPage.Icon>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <ContentPage>

        </ContentPage>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```